# Question related to dimension of a manifold of zeros over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F \in \mathbb{z}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ be a form of degree $d>1$. Let $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ be the manifold of real zeros of $F$ (I am using the notation of an article I am reading here). Let $B = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n: |\mathbf{x}| \leq 1\}$, where $|\cdot|$ is a sup norm. Define $V_{\mathbb{R}}(B)$ to be the manifold of zeros of $F$ in the interior of $B$.

I was wondering if someone could explain why $\dim V_{\mathbb{R}} = \dim V_{\mathbb{R}}(B)$? Thank you!

Comment: When you write $\dim$, which dimension are you exactly referring to?

Comment: I suppose you mean dimension as a manifold and not as an algebraic variety.

Comment: It doesn't say specifically in the article, but I am guessing as a manifold because the author states $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ as a manifold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may answer your question: since $F$ is a form, i.e. it is homogeneous, a tuple $a:=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is a root of $F$ if and only if the tuple 
$c (a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is a root for any nonzero $c$. That is, for any root $a$, the entire line spanned by $a$ consists of roots as well. This shows that what matters is the direction of a root ($n$-tuple) and not its norm. This is why we can restrict our attention inside the unit ball without loss of generality.